What is the way to APDU communication with sim or NFC SE on android？
I want to write an app through Android Studio to communicate APDU with the SIM on the mobile phone, and I have searched three ways

By include org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar, call the function to communicate
Use android.se.omapi, call the function to communicate
Call the TelephonyManager iccTransmitApduBasicChannel method for communication, etc

I found the method 1 tutorial link "https://github.com/seek-for-android/pool/wiki/UsingSmartCardAPI"
Based on this tutorial, I got stuck in Reader[] readers = seService.getReaders(); In this case, an exception is thrown
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: service not connected to system"
I see in the "https://groups.google.com/g/seek-for-android/c/zMdDdKDNdKk/m/QjUnQ9RIkbYJ" link to answer
"On a real device you you cannot access the UICC, because this requires
modification on the baseband firmware, which can only be provided by
the hardware manufacturer.", does it mean that an individual cannot write an APP to communicate with the SIM card on the phone?
For method 3, I see that the api for APDU communication are Deprecated as of API30, and that they require the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission
This permission is a system permission, which is difficult to obtain for ordinary apps
The Android version of the my phone is Android14
My question is

What's the difference between methods 1 and 2, same named OMAPI
Which method should I choose to continue my development with more ease?

Thanks
See details of problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I used android.se.omapi rather than org.simalliance.openmobileapi to access the sim, thank you
